# Error while loading Angular JS controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<html>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testControl">    
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="x in phones">
           {{x.name}}<br />{{x.title}}
       </li>    
    </ul>
 </body>   
</html>
```

JS File

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('testControl', function($scope){
    $scope.phones = [
        {name: 'iPhone 6', title: 'Apple created'},
        {name: 'Samsumg Galaxy 2', title: 'Samsung created'}
    ];
});
```

JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Lxk5p905/

Comment: Isn't this same as the other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053422/angular-js-control-not-rendering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle options => `No wrap in <head>`

**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/yo5nn3kc/)** - no code changed

Comment: Can you please explain this? I added the <script src=""></script> part in my <head> tags in my application. But it still doesn't show up.

Comment: This is why I prefer [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) for Angular

Comment: This just means your script is loaded between your head tags. See more info from the jsfiddle docs. http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-options. You're code is working fine, so as @adam0101 mentioned, provide a plunkr if you are having more trouble and we'll take a look with you